# TinyMCE 4 - create H1 with strong and class

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a question.

I would like to create something like this:

```
<h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>TEXT</strong></h1>
```

**Unfortunately, I can't do this.
I've tested with this solutions (style_formats**):

```
{title: 'Header uppercase',block: 'h1', classes: 'text-uppercase'},
```

*Result:*

```
<h1 class="text-uppercase">TEXT</h1>
```

**Next try:**

```
{title: 'Header uppercase',block: 'h1',inline: 'strong', classes: 'text-uppercase'},
```

*Result:*

```
<p><strong class="text-uppercase">TEXT</strong></p>
```

**Acceptable solution for me is:**

```
<h1><strong>TEXT</strong></h1>
```